# Updating a MongoDB array subelement field

Tags: php, mongodb

I can't seem to figure out how to update a single element within a subarray. I'd like to update `images > 59db1c3654819952005897 > sort` to be 5

```
"_id" : 34,  
"images": [
        {
            "59db1c3654819952005897": {
                "name": "1024x1024.png",
                "size": "19421",
                "sort": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "59db1c3652cda581935479": {
                "name": "200x200.png",
                "size": "52100",
                "sort": 3
            }
        }
    ]
```

Here's what I've tried but neither work:

```
updateOne(['_id' => 34], ['$set' => ["images.59db1c3654819952005897.sort" => 5]])

updateOne(['_id' => 34], ['$set' => ["images.$.59db1c3654819952005897.sort" => 5]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) and the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to update the embedded documents field, you need to include the array in the query otherwise it won't work. In the above case, the revised update operation would be

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        "_id": 34,
        "images.59db1c3654819952005897": { "$exists": true } // <-- include array in query
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "images.$.59db1c3654819952005897.sort": 5
        }
    }
)
```